# how to get all HTML elements with specific text by jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

How can I get all elements with specific text(inner HTML) in an HTML document by jsoup?

for example all elements with text **test** :

```
<html><head><title>for example></title></head>
<body>
<div id="div1" class='test'>
test
<p id='p1'>test<a id='a1'>test</a></p>
<a id='a2'>test</a>
<img src='' id='img1' alt='test'>
<p id='p2'>example</p>
</div>
</body></html>
```

note that I don't want to use tags' id or tags' name for selecting elements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>for example></title></head><body><div id=\"div1\" class='test'>test<p id='p1'>test<a id='a1'>test</a></p><a id='a2'>test</a><img src='' id='img1' alt='test'><p id='p2'>example</p></div></body></html>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements elements = doc.select("*:containsOwn(test)");

    for(Element element:elements)
    {
        System.out.println(element.toString()+"\n");
    }
```

This will give the output for tags with id: div1,p1,a1,a2.

Comment: Glad to help you @atefeh-rashidi ! If the answer solved your problem click the V to mark the question as answered.